# JS & jQuery function that hides some DIVs on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div `navigation`, inside this div is a div `login`. I use javascript that displays divs `login_name_field`, `login_pw_field`, `register_btn`, `do_login_btn`, `hide_login` and hides the div `login` when I click the `login` div.

The `hide_login` div, when clicked hides all the newly displayed divs including itself and displays the original `login` div. It all works like a charm, but I would like to have one more function that does the same as `hide_login` but is triggered by clicking anywhere outside the main `navigation` div. I tried to adjust my code, but I am getting **is not defined** error on the new `clicked` vars.

Please have a look at the code below. Thank you all for reading and in advance for the replies :) Have a nice holiday.

```js
    $( "#login_btn" ).click(function() {
    
                        $('#login_name_field').toggle()
                        $('#login_pw_field').toggle()
                        $('#register_btn').toggle()
                        $('#login_btn').toggle()
                        $('#do_login_btn').toggle()
                        $('#hide_login').toggle()
                        var loginClicked = 1;
    });

    $( "#hide_login" ).click(function() {
    
                        $('#login_name_field').toggle()
                        $('#login_pw_field').toggle()
                        $('#register_btn').toggle()
                        $('#login_btn').toggle()
                        $('#do_login_btn').toggle()
                        $('#hide_login').toggle()
                        var loginClicked = 0;
    });

    $( "#navigation_bar" ).not().click(function() {
        if(loginClicked == 1){
            $( "#hide_login" ).click();
        }
    });
```

```html
    <div id="navigation_bar">
    
      <!-- DO Login BTN -> runs the login function -->              
      <div id="do_login_btn" class="do_button" style="display: none;">
        <input type="submit" id="nav_btn" name="whatever" value="Log In!">
      </div> 
                                    
      <!-- Hide Login BTN -->
        <div id="hide_login" class="hide_button" style="display: none;">
      </div>            
                                    
      <!-- Login PW field -> input for login query -->
      <div id="login_pw_field" class="button" style="display: none;">
        <div id="field_div">
          <input type="password" name="login_pw_field" value="password" class="p_reset" id="password">
        </div>
      </div>
                        
      <!-- Login NAME/Email field -> input for login query -->
      <div id="login_name_field" class="button" style="display: none;">
        <div id="field_div">
          <input type="text" class="n_reset" name="login_name_field" id="name" value="Name / Email"></input>
        </div>
      </div>
                               
      <!-- Register BTN -> forwards to Account Recovery Page -->
      <div id="acc_rec_btn" class="button" style="display: none;">
        <p id="center">Account Recovery</p>
      </div>
                                
      <!-- Login BTN -> displays Login NAME & PW fields, DO Login BTN, Register BTN -->                 
      <div id="login_btn" class="button" style="display: block;">
        <p id="center">Log In</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Also it appears that the `$( "#navigation_bar" ).not().click(function()` only triggers when I am clicking inside the `navigation_bat` div instead of outside of it. I thought the `not()` takes care of that. Well, let me know what you think :)

Comment: Aside: if you're applying the same action to several elements, just select them all `$('#login_name_field, #login_pw_field, etc').toggle()`. Your understanding of not is not what you think. http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: Can you post the relevant chunk of HTML please

Comment: Added the code ;) Also, thank you for the multi select idea.

Comment: I am staring at the documentation and I can't seem to figure out how to rewrite the code to do the intended. Should it be `not($( "#navigation_bar" )).click(function()` ??

Comment: not will filter out elements, so you need something selected to filter.

Comment: Maybe this would help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it

Comment: yeah so I want this function to run whenever I click anywhere outside the `navigation_bar` div. So isn't what I wrote correct?

Comment: @uditbansal Wooow. It works! I have to adjust it a little but it works perfect. Posted the solution above. Tagged the question solved. If you want the accepted answer feel free to post an actual answer since I can't accept the comment :(. But thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the appreciation!!! Merry Christmas!!! :)

Comment: @james: do not do "Posted the solution above. Tagged the question solved". Just answer your own question bellow, and then accept own answer when SO will allow so.

Comment: Awwww, that's how you're supposed to do it? I am sorry. I don't really want to redo the whole question above now. I promise I'll do it right next time, ok? Promise!

Comment: You can copy-paste the answer to an actual answer and then [roll back](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20774902/revisions) to the previous version of the question. Takes maybe 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

According to your advices I have the code working now and it looks like this:

```
$( "#login_btn" ).click(function() {

    $('#login_name_field, #login_pw_field, #register_btn, #login_btn, #do_login_btn, #hide_login').toggle()

});

$( "#hide_login" ).click(function() {

    $('#login_name_field, #login_pw_field, #register_btn, #acc_rec_btn, #login_btn, #do_login_btn, #hide_login').css("display", "none")
$('#login_btn').css("display", "block");
});

    $(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $("#navigation_bar");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        $( "#hide_login" ).click();
    }
});
```

I have also adjusted the `hide_login` function. The way it was implemented before with the new solution when I kept clicking outside the `navigation_bar` div it keep displaying and hiding the elements instead just hiding them when they are already displayed. Now it works perfectly.